# For some reason or the other my gridview is stuck in one position and my Textview. I am using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I am not able to drag the grid to the center, bottom, left, right or top. Its just stuck there. How do i position it to the center. the grid consists of 4 items 2x2. how do i fix it in the code

this is the activity_main.xml which i am not sure how to modify

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:baselineAligned="false">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Pick your cuisine"
    android:layout_weight="1.67"
    android:layout_gravity="top">
    android:text="@string/Pick your cuisine,"
</TextView>

<GridView
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:columnWidth="100dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:layout_width="220dp"
     android:layout_height="130dp"
     android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:backgroundTint="#C0C0C0"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply" />
```

this is the grid.java which i also dont yet understand how to properly modify

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:baselineAligned="false">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Pick your cuisine"
    android:layout_weight="1.67"
    android:layout_gravity="top">
    android:text="@string/Pick your cuisine,"
</TextView>

<GridView
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:columnWidth="100dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:layout_width="220dp"
     android:layout_height="130dp"
     android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:backgroundTint="#C0C0C0"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply" />


</LinearLayout>
```

this is the mainactivity.java it contains all the images

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView grid;
String[] web = {
        "Indian Food",
        "Malay Food",
        "Arab Food",
        "Chinese Food",


} ;
int[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,

};

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
                                                                                                     grid.setOnItemClickListener(new                                                      AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "       +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dragging system in Android Studio is very tricky. The best way is to do it directly from XML.

Always start with NOT having android:layout_margin*, android:padding*, android:gravity, android:layout_gravity fields. Then start adding these attributes one by one, and look in your Design tab to see how it looks.

I think in order to bring it in the absolute center, you should add android:padding* attributes, and set android:layout_width and android:layout_height to "match_parent"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:baselineAligned="false">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:text="Pick your cuisine"
    android:layout_weight="1.67"
    android:layout_gravity="top">
    android:text="@string/Pick your cuisine,"
</TextView>

<GridView
     android:numColumns="2"
     android:columnWidth="100dp"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:paddingTop="20dp"
     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
     android:paddingBottom="20dp"
     android:paddingRight="20dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:backgroundTint="#C0C0C0"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:backgroundTintMode="multiply" />
```

Comment: when i make the layout_height=matchparent, it drags the grip upwards, but when i keep it 130dp its fixed at the center. the part with the paddings gives errors though. I didnt know positioning would be such a pain, is there like some sort of an online chart of something to save and review when i need to position grids ?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a tool yet. Yes, position is painful in Android Studio because it is a new product and is not yet fully mature.

Can you share what is the error that you see with padding?

Comment: Error:(22, -1) android-apt-compiler: [AndroidCustomGridView] C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidCustomGridView\AndroidCustomGridView\res\layout\activity_main.xml:22: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_paddingTop' in package 'android'

Comment: Apologies, **remove** the `layout_` prefix from padding properties. I'm editing the code to reflect the change.

Comment: Oh yea got it ! its still a bit out of shape though but its fine ill play around with it till its fixed. Thanks alot !